# DWR invoke error in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, dwr

I am using `Spring 3.05` and `DWR 3.0rc1` in my application for making AJAX calls. In local environment, i.e. Eclipse & Tomcat Server, it's working fine but in Clustered Environment I am getting the following errors while invoking `DWR` and a script error is coming saying `DWR` is not defined, but I am able to see `myApplication/dwr/index.html` properly.

Error Log:

> Skipping 'script' due to NoClassDefFoundError on org.directwebremoting.create.ScriptedCreator. Cause: org/apache/bsf/BSFException
>
> Skipping 'pageflow' due to ClassNotFoundException on org.directwebremoting.beehive.PageFlowCreator. Cause: Beehive/Weblogic jar file not available.
>
> adding creator type: none = class org.directwebremoting.create.NullCreator
>
> adding creator type: new = class org.directwebremoting.create.NewCreator

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that jars are not included in the classpath. Can you please check whether it is included?

Comment: They are included in class path orelse my Java file of DWR would have given error and the maven build is also successful..  In my eclipse its working fine but in HTTPS clustered environment its not working. Can anyone tell me how can I put a jar in lib and refer my POM to refer it during build.. I am using Maven build . Please help